# Why the img will be invisible after click the color change js function?

Tags: javascript, django, cloudinary

I have a django project including the change color function with js, but the img will be invisible after I use those function. Btw this img has been uploaded to cloudinary. something I need to re-config?

Below is my js function for the changing color, I have already set the img.crossOrigin = ' ' to prevent from the Error of 'getImageData' :

```
var mug = document.getElementById("mug");
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var originalPixels = null;
var currentPixels = null;

function getPixels(img) {
    img.crossOrigin = '';
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    originalPixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    currentPixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);

    img.onload = null;
}


function hexToRGB(hex)
{
var long = parseInt(hex.replace(/^#/, ""), 16);
return {
    R: (long >>> 16) & 0xff,
    G: (long >>> 8) & 0xff,
    B: long & 0xff
  };
 }

function changeColor()
{
    var mug = document.getElementById("mug");
    if(!originalPixels) return; // Check if image has loaded
    var newColor = hexToRGB(document.getElementById("color").value);

    for(var I = 0, L = originalPixels.data.length; I < L; I += 4)
    {
        if(currentPixels.data[I + 3] > 0) // If it's not a transparent pixel
        {
            currentPixels.data[I] = originalPixels.data[I] / 255 * newColor.R;
            currentPixels.data[I + 1] = originalPixels.data[I + 1] / 255 * newColor.G;
            currentPixels.data[I + 2] = originalPixels.data[I + 2] / 255 * newColor.B;
        }
    }

    ctx.putImageData(currentPixels, 0, 0);
    mug.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}

function changeColor1()
{
    var mug = document.getElementById("mug");
    if(!originalPixels) return; // Check if image has loaded
    var newColor = hexToRGB(document.getElementById("color1").value);
        {

    for(var I = 0, L = originalPixels.data.length; I < L; I += 4)
    {
        if(currentPixels.data[I + 3] > 0) // If it's not a transparent pixel
            currentPixels.data[I] = originalPixels.data[I] / 255 * newColor.R;
            currentPixels.data[I + 1] = originalPixels.data[I + 1] / 255 * newColor.G;
            currentPixels.data[I + 2] = originalPixels.data[I + 2] / 255 * newColor.B;
        }
    }

    ctx.putImageData(currentPixels, 0, 0);
    mug.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}

function changeColor2()
{
    var mug = document.getElementById("mug");
    if(!originalPixels) return; // Check if image has loaded
    var newColor = hexToRGB(document.getElementById("color2").value);
        {

    for(var I = 0, L = originalPixels.data.length; I < L; I += 4)
    {
        if(currentPixels.data[I + 3] > 0) // If it's not a transparent pixel
            currentPixels.data[I] = originalPixels.data[I] / 255 * newColor.R;
            currentPixels.data[I + 1] = originalPixels.data[I + 1] / 255 * newColor.G;
            currentPixels.data[I + 2] = originalPixels.data[I + 2] / 255 * newColor.B;
        }
    }

    ctx.putImageData(currentPixels, 0, 0);
    mug.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}

function changeColor3()
{
    var mug = document.getElementById("mug");
    if(!originalPixels) return; // Check if image has loaded
    var newColor = hexToRGB(document.getElementById("color3").value);
        {

    for(var I = 0, L = originalPixels.data.length; I < L; I += 4)
    {
        if(currentPixels.data[I + 3] > 0) // If it's not a transparent pixel
            currentPixels.data[I] = originalPixels.data[I] / 255 * newColor.R;
            currentPixels.data[I + 1] = originalPixels.data[I + 1] / 255 * newColor.G;
            currentPixels.data[I + 2] = originalPixels.data[I + 2] / 255 * newColor.B;
        }
    }

    ctx.putImageData(currentPixels, 0, 0);
    mug.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}
```

Below is my template file:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}


{% block content %}

<script src="{% static 'js/color_change.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="container">
    <h1>{{ details.name }}</h1>
    <div id="colorpicker"></div>
    <img id="mug" width="500" height="500" src="{{ details.img.url }}"  onload="getPixels(this)"/>
     <button id="color1" value="#33FFBD" type="button" onclick="changeColor1();" style="background-color: #33FFBD;width: 50px;height: 50px;"></button>
    <button id="color2" value="#FFA500" type="button" onclick="changeColor2();" style="background-color: orange;width: 50px;height: 50px;"></button>
    <button id="color3" value="#b22222" type="button" onclick="changeColor3();" style="background-color: firebrick;width: 50px;height: 50px;"></button>
    <p>{{ details.desc }}</p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: the img src will be "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo..........." after I click the button for js function.